# Why is my code for a battleship game running over and over again?

Tags: python, class

So I am trying to create a very simple 1-player battleship game in python. Where the computer randomly places its ships in the rows and columns, and the player guesses which row and column a ship is in. My current problem is that my code does that, however it prints the board out each time and also seems to make the choices for the player as well.

```
import random
#Make board
board = [
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
]

# List to refer to columns by letter, since that is how a typical battleship game is
#initiated
letters2Numbers = {
    'A': 0,
    'B': 1,
    'C': 2,
    'D': 3,
    'E': 4,
}


#Function to ask the user for their board position
def generateShips():
    for a in range (0,55):
        row = random.randrange(1,6)
        column = random.choice(['A','B','C','D','E'])
        rowNumber = row
        columnNumber = column

        return int(row) - 1, letters2Numbers[column]

def askUser():
    column = input("column (A to E):")
    while column not in "ABCDE":
        print("That column is wrong! It should be A, B, C, D or E")
        column = input("column (A to E):")

    row = input("row (1 to 5):")
    while row not in "12345":
        print("That row is wrong! it should be 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5")
        row = input("row (1 to 5):")
    return int(row) - 1, letters2Numbers[column]

def printBoard(board):
    # Shows the board, one row at a time, labelled
    print("  A B C D E")
    print(" +-+-+-+-+-+")
    rowNumber = 1
    for row in board:
        print("%d|%s|" % (rowNumber, "|".join(row)))
        print(" +-+-+-+-+-+")
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1




# Now clear the screen, and the other player starts guessing
print("\n"*50)

guessesBoard = [
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
]


# Keep playing until we have 5 right guesses
guesses = 0
while guesses < 5:
    print("Guess a battleship location")
    rowNumber, columnNumber = askUser()

    if guessesBoard[rowNumber][columnNumber] != ' ':
        print("You have already guessed that place!")
        continue

    # Check that there are no repeats
    if board[rowNumber][columnNumber] == 'X':
        print("HIT!")
        guessesBoard[rowNumber][columnNumber] = 'X'
        guesses = guesses + 1
    else:
        guessesBoard[rowNumber][columnNumber] = '.'
        print("MISS!")

    printBoard(guessesBoard)
print("GAME OVER!")
```

This is my code so far. If you run it, you'll see the error I'm talking about.

Comment: You never asked for any user input. The program just plays it by itself (using random).

Answer (score 1):

You never ask the player for choices; you print a message suggesting that you're about to do so, but then your code charges ahead and uses the row and column from ship generation.  Nowhere in your program do you accept user input.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use function input() rather than random.SOMETHING. Then your input will not be choosen by PC.

Then to convert user input (which always returns a string) to a number, you can use something like:

```
a = input("perhaps a number: ")
if not a.isdigit():
    raise ValueError("I said number :(")
a = int(a)
```

You probably don't want to raise the error, I am just demonstrating what you can build on.

I am waiting for further development of this question. :)

Comment: Hi! I edited it so it now asks the user for an input. That seemed to fix most of the problem, except now in the shell it runs a huge space of 20 blank lines?

Comment: I guess these will be the `print("\n"*50)` ;)

Comment: Btw, I ran your code and noticed that you never set the ships, so the playing field is empty.